# ModelState.IsValid doesn't validate collection properties and always return true

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, fluentvalidation

I have these classes

```
    public class Shape
    {
        public Shape()
        {
            ShapeDetails = new List<ShapeDetail>();
        }

        public int ID { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public List<ShapeDetail> ShapeDetails { get; set; }
    }

    public class ShapeValidator : AbstractValidator<Shape>
    {
        public ShapeValidator()
        {
            RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().Length(1, 225);
        }
    }

public class ShapeDetail
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public decimal RangeFrom { get; set; }
    public decimal RangeTo { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }
    public int ShapeID { get; set; }
    [NonPersistent]
    public Shape Shape { get; set; }
}

public class ShapeDetailValidator : AbstractValidator<ShapeDetail>
{
    public ShapeDetailValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.RangeFrom).NotEmpty().LessThan(100);
        RuleFor(x => x.RangeTo).NotEmpty().LessThan(100);
        RuleFor(x => x.Price).NotEmpty().LessThan(9999999999);
    }
}
```

When I call `ModelState.IsValid` on `Shape`, it always return true, it seems like it's not validating `ShapeDetail`, how do I include the `ShapeDetails` in the validation?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

found the answer, need to add `RuleForEach` in `ShapeValidator`

```
public class ShapeValidator : AbstractValidator<Shape>
{
    public ShapeValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Name).NotEmpty().Length(1, 225);
        RuleForEach(x => x.ShapeDetails).SetValidator(new ShapeDetailValidator());
    }
}
```

source: https://fluentvalidation.net/start#collections